# How to prove that this finite sum is true

Tags: fourier-analysis

Does anyone know how I could show that

$$
    \sum_{n = -N_1}^{N_1}{e^{-i\omega n}} = \frac{\sin( \omega ( N_1 - \frac{1}{
2} ))}  {\sin( \frac{\omega}{2} ) }
$$

Solution: 
$$
  = \sum_{n=0}^{N_1} ( e^{i \omega n} + e^{-i \omega n} ) - 1
$$

$$
   = \sum_{n=0}^{N_1} ( e^{i \omega n} + e^{-i \omega n} ) - 1
$$

$$
   = \frac{1}{1 - e^{i \omega}} + \frac{1}{1 - e^{-i\omega} } - 1
$$

$$
    = \frac{1 - e^{i \omega} + 1 - e^{-i \omega} }{  ( 1 - e^{i \omega} )( 1 - e^{-i \omega} )} - 1
$$

$$
  = \frac{2 - e^{i \omega}- e^{-i \omega} }{  ( 1 - e^{i \omega} )( 1 - e^{-i \omega} )} - 1
$$

Really don't know how to get the $\sin$ function from here.

Comment: Why did you divide & multiply by $2i?$

Comment: When I try to use geometric series it starts getting even more complex,as shown in the question.I know in order to have sin I need to have 2i somewhere, thats why I introduced it.

Comment: the summation formula you have is of infinite Geometric Series, but in your case the number of terms is not necessarily infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: It is a Geometric Series 
 and using [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) $$\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$\sum_{n = -N_1}^{N_1}{e^{-i\omega n}} $$
$$= e^{i\omega N_1}\cdot\frac{(e^{-iw})^{2N_1+2}-1}{e^{-iw}-1}$$

$$=\frac{e^{\frac{(2N_1-1)iw}2}-e^{-\frac{(2N_1-1)iw}2}}{e^{\frac{iw}2}-e^{-\frac{iw}2}}$$

$$=\frac{2i\sin \frac{(2N_1-1)w}2}{2i\sin \frac w2}$$

Comment: And use $i$, not $j$.  Because it's an $I$maginary number, not $J$imaginary number.  :)

Comment: @bob.sacamento, have you seen the notation in the question?

Comment: Well, of course I was hoping KillaKem would see my comment too. Just a joke. Engineers always use $j$. I love to rag them about it.

Comment: Just after reading @bob.sacamento's comment I realized $\,j=i=\sqrt{-1}\,$ . I know some people somewhere write $\,j\,$ , but I think the overwhelming majority of mathematicians in the world and in this sector of the galaxy write $\,i\,$ . People should be aware of this, imo.

Comment: Changed from j to i.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Electrical engineers who work with circuits, Smith charts, and the like use $j$; all other sentient carbon-based life forms use $i$.  The reason for this is that they (the EE's) discovered current before imaginary numbers.

Comment: Which identity did you use to move from the summation to that expression just below it?

Comment: @KillaKem, so did I. Please find the edited answer.

Comment: @KillaKem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Comment: Seriously guys, I didn't expect anybody to change anything.  It was just a joke.  Even though it should, of course, be $i$ instead of $j$.